# confusion in implementing usb interface for programming cortex m3

Tags: arm, embedded, usb, bootloader, cortex-m

i am thinking of creating a PCB with a NXP - LPC1756FBD80. It has a cortex m3 chip on it. I want to be able to program the chip on the pcb using a usb cable which i can directly connect to my laptop. But im not sure if im doing this right ive checked the datasheet for the chip and it has a section on suggested USB interface solutions. This section has a circuit but im not sure if this is enough to implement the functionality that i want. Any inputs from you guys would be appreciated. 
thank you

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what "program the chip on the pcb using a usb cable" means for you? Are you trying to access the ARM Debug Port via a USB based solution?

Comment: well basically im making my own board with a cortex m3 chip. i want to be able to write all the code onto the m3 using usb. This was i just have to plug the usb on my laptop and upload the code. Similar to how we upload a sketch on arduino boards.

Comment: i would like to access the debug port as well using the usb based solution do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new chip, you need to get code into it through something like a JTAG port or the chip's serial (UART) port & primary bootloader.  "Out of the box", you can't load new code into it over USB.

You need to implement a secondary bootloader that runs after the MCU's on-chip bootloader runs.

Check out NXP's [**App Note AN10866**](http://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/48329-102-3-259149/Nxp.Application_Notes_14.pdf) - "LPC 1700 Secondary USB Bootloader".

This is the text from the beginning of the app note:

> A secondary bootloader is a piece of code which allows a user
>   application code to be downloaded using alternative channels other
>   than the standard UART0 used by the primary bootloader (on-chip). The
>   primary bootloader is the firmware that resides in a microcontroller’s
>   boot ROM block and is executed on power-up and resets. After the boot
>   ROM’s execution the secondary bootloader is executed. The secondary
>   bootloader in turn will then execute the end-user application.
>
> This application note uses USB as an example for developing a
>   secondary bootloader on a LPC1700 series microcontroller.

If that sounds like what you need (I believe it is), congratulations.  Also LPCWARE has some files & info relevant to the topic.

Comment: hey thanks that sounds like what i need :)
also is it possible to just use a ftdi usb to serial cable and program the chip ? For my design keeping the weight as low as possible is very important. if the cable can do the job then i wont need the usb.

Comment: @user2055491 Yes, that's easy. Best use a USB to serial with 3.3V levels, then you'll only need a connector. For automatic operation you'll need TXD, RXD, DTR (-> Reset) and RTS (-> selects boot mode). Use FlashMagic or lpc21isp software. AFAIK that works for all recent NXP controllers.